# Converting query to Lambda Expression

Tags: c#, lambda

In mysql,

```
select distinct(trim(containerType)) from productIn where containerType <> '' group by containerNo
```

How can I make expression that query using Lambda?

Ex)

```
List<string> containerTypes = new List<string>();
containerTypes = productInRepository.GroupBy(x=> x.containerNo).Select(?????).ToList();
```

[image]

Comment: It's been a while since I've done MySql, but is your SQL even *legal*? A select on a field not included in the group by?

Comment: I just test it, yes it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think groupby field which is not in result select means the same as orderby this field.

```
List<string> containerTypes = productInRepository
                .Where(x => x.containerType != string.Empty)
                .OrderBy(x => x.containerNo)
                .Select(x => x.containerType.Trim())
                .Distinct();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
List<string> containerTypes = productInRepository
    .Where(x => x.containerType != string.Empty)
    .GroupBy(x=> x.containerNo)
    .Select(x => x.containerType.Trim())
    .ToList();
```